# Z3 / SMTLIB2 support for `distinct`

Tags: z3, smt

I've been using the (ML) z3 bindings for a while, and the API function

```
val mk_distinct : context -> ast array -> ast
```

has served faithfully for many years. Am now trying to switch 
to the SMTLIB2 interface, but I find that the `distinct` command
is `unsupported`. For example, the query:

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(distinct x y)
(assert (= x y))
(check-sat)
```

yields the response:

```
unsupported
; distinct  
sat
```

on the web-demo. Is there some workaround?

Thanks!

Ranjit.

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted if you ever come back on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `(assert (distinct x y))` instead of `(distinct x y)`.
Here is a link to the updated example: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/uVrX

Comment: terrific! I'm assuming this is SMTLIB2 compliant btw? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is part of the standard.